# rabbitmq event driven microservices

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices

Microservice architecture and sharing common application data.

Scenario being: 
There are today 17 microservices for some online social media service and 9 of them need to know who is connected to who in order for their function to work. To prevent each service constantly asking the "authentication" or "connections" microserice for the list, all services register to recieve a copy of the connections per user and store in a cache.

A proposal for the mechanism to deliver the data, or instruction to fetch data could be rabbitmq.

However, each microservice is a cluster of docker containers orchestrated by k8s for scalability.

Each container registers to listen to a collection of exchanges they are interested in... so for the "news feed" service that could be say 5 connections...

Below is an illustration of the proposed setup:
[image: data workflow]

- T1 - user A accept a friend request
- T2 - The connections service (MS1) makes the connection in its primary database
- T3 - MS1 published to a rabbitmq exchange the said event
- T4 - rabbitmq exchange emits to all Q's (ie all other microservices registered)
- T5 - All the nodes within the MS2 cluster pickup the event and act... their action (in this case) will be to update the cache of the friend connections.
- T6 - user A requests the data for their newsfeed, MS2 now queries its database with the use of its local cache

This is all good:

- The connection service didn't know or care who got the data, only that it should emit to 1 exchange via the single rabbitmq entry point
- The developer of MS2 only needed to know about the location of the rabbitmq instance
- The developer of all the other services the same.. they handle the data in their own brilliant way.

The 1 exception is.. there were 3 instances of MS2 so that would be 3 database writes.. if the system scales to 10 that would be 10 db writes etc etc.

**Question**
How is this problem bypassed... how to ensure only 1 of the MS2 instances will act?

Should the newsfeed microservice be delivered with its own internal q system to manage the data from the exchange? Is it possible to route all the messages via the load balancer so only 1 instance of MS2 gets a message? I don't want to start managing lots of lots of queues by hand as this will be a pain and defeat the simplicity of the exchange design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, all instances if M2 will *share* a queue and work using the *competing consumer* pattern, every messages is consumed once and if all instance of M2 goes down the queue grows until they come back up again.

M2, M3 and M4 will each create ONE queue for what M1 publishes.
Let's name them them
M2_from_M1, M3_from_M1 and M4_from_M1.
They will all also create a binding against the exchange M1 uses and on the routing key for this message.

Now, instances of M2 will all consume from M2_from_M1, instances of M3 will all consume from M3_from_M1 and so on.

If all instances of any of these are down it's queue will start to fill up but that is fine since it will be consumed later.

Regarding the overall architecture. Try first with actually making the call between M2 and M1, access time between pods is probably very fast and you could probably cache both in M1 and in M2 for a while. Worst outcome is that you see news from people you no longer follow, or that you don't get news from new contacts.

Comment: Yes i can simply call M1 from M2 no problem, but this doesn't scale well and all M* need to know the location of all other M's.

Comment: If all of M2 instances register to a Q, then M1 needs to know the name of the Q it should publish to... but then it also needs to know the name of all the microservices that need the data.. after a very short amount of time there would be many queues... hence the idea of the exchange.. but  then this brings the problem mentioned in the OP

Comment: No, M1 publishes a message with a routing key but doesn't care what queues bind to that routing key. M2 creates a queue and binding but collectivly consumes from it. It's this tutorial https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html

Comment: Regarding the location of M*. In kubernetes each service gets a dns name and this is how you call it. You don't need to know any individual pod. This is the documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: I think i must be missing a part of the puzzle. If M1 publishes to a simple work queue and on the other end instances of M2 and M3 and M4 decided to listen.. then it is a 1st come 1st serve.. or competing consumer pattern, however M2/3/4 all needed the data... to get around this M1 publishes to an exchange and M2/3/4 subscribe to the exchange

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-javascript.html

Comment: but the bit where things get messed up is.. when M2 scales.. then all instances of M2 react to the published call where we only want 1 of them to react.. but this doesn't just happen in M2 but also in all other microservices that horizontally scale but are subscribing to the exchange

Comment: the solution i overlooked was not setting exclusive to true! doh!

Comment: I don't think exclusive is the correct way forward. I'll expand on my answer to explain how I think it should work.

Comment: It does seem to work.. n instances of M2 assert their own queue not as exclusive but with the same name, eg "queue_M2". Then the core consumer pattern automatically kicks in.. but it this is not correct would love to know before i move my project too deep into this direction.